# How to mock a HttpResponse in Asp.NetCore controller?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, mocking

I am working on a Asp.NetCore application, and one of the controllers looks like this:

```
[HttpPost, Route("setCookies")]
public int SetCookies([FromBody] Dictionary<string, string> cookies)
{
    foreach (var cookie in cookies)
    {
        Response.Cookies.Append(cookie.Key, cookie.Value, new CookieOptions() { Path = "/", HttpOnly = true });
    }

    return 1;
}
```

And now I am trying to add unit test case for this controller.

After I create an instance of the controller by

```
var _controller = new Controller();
```

and call the method

```
_controller.SetCookies(<some parameter>);
```

It shows that `Response` is *null*.

I checked the metadate and it shows that `Response` is a *readonly* property in the abstract base class `ControllerBase` like this:

```
public HttpResponse Response { get; }
```

So, is there anyway to mock the `Response` property?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The request and response are associated with the controller's current `HttpContext`, which you will need to set via the `ControllerContext` when setting up the controller.

```
//...
//Arrange
HttpContext httpContext = new DefaultHttpContext();
//Controller needs a controller context 
var controllerContext = new ControllerContext() {
    HttpContext = httpContext,
};
//assign context to controller
var _controller = new MyController(){
    ControllerContext = controllerContext,
};

//Act
int actual = _controller.SetCookies(<some parameter>);

//...
```

The [`DefaultHttpContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.defaulthttpcontext) used in the example above, will have a *non-null* empty request and response by default.  This should give you access to the response to exercise your unit test as desired.